# Scala - how to initialize object with data from another class

Tags: scala, singleton, args

In my Scala application (ver 2.11), I want to use the main args all over my App.

In order to do so, I thought to create an object (which is singleton in Scala), and to init it with main-args

Something like this:

```
  object MyMain{
    def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {
      //how to set SingletonArgs with args???
    }

  object SingletonArgs{
    def getArg0():String{...}
    def getArg1():String{...}
  }

  class AnotherClass(){
   def printArg0(){
     println(SingletonArgs.getArg0)
   }
}
```

How can I init the SingletonArgs?

Is there a different way to share the main args?

Comment: Don't do this, just pass an instance of `SingletonArgs` to the underling class. This is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and is one of the five SOLID principles of software engineering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As *Tim* mentioned in his comment: don't do this.

If you don't want to clutter your code with these args, you can use `implicits`:

```
object MyMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val myArgs = MyArgs(args(0), args(1))
    new AnotherClass().printArg0()
  }
}

case class MyArgs(arg0: String, arg1: String)

class AnotherClass()(implicit args: MyArgs) {
  def printArg0() {
    println(args.arg0)
  }
}
```